# worker to worker communication in Sparkling Water

Tags: apache-spark, sparkling-water

I think it is implied from the system diagram that sparkling water implemented worker to worker direct communication (without going back to the master). Can someone point out where is the code is that feature?

Comment: As per i understand you question. you need to share your code with all cluster node without submitting jar right ?

Answer (score 0):

Sparkling Water is using the exact same communication pattern as Spark does. The driver starts the computation and orchestrates the work amongst several worker nodes. Sparkling Water is basically just Spark application with H2O node running in each Spark's JVM ( for all executors and driver )